# How to exclude values when passing multivalue parameters in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I have an Action that opens another report and it passes a multivalue parameter.  Is there a way to exclude for example, the first value of the multivalue parameter?

Comment: Would setting the first parameters "General Properties" to "Accept Blank" and "Accept Null" solve your issue?

Comment: What I mean is, even if the first parameter is selected.  It should be excluded when the multiparameter values are being passed.  For example, if I have checkboxes dogs, cats, and birds and then they are all checked.  When the multiparameter values are passed, I want only cats and birds.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using SQL Server for your queries.. when you pass the list of parameters into your subreport, I would take the parameter pass it to a splitstring function and then exclude the first row and then use the result in your where clause for your subreport parameter.

This way you have flexibility to exclude what ever row you want by passing the row number as a parameter as well.. just saying.. and you cal also check that you have more than one parameter selected before excluding it.. else you won't get a result back